# socket stops receiving new data

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sockets

Before I start explaining my issue I must say I'm inexperienced in networking/sockets (probably the explanation for the reason I'm having troubles)

Without further ado:

The situation is as follows
I have a desktop WPF application that has to receive a constant stream of data from a server, using a socket.
For now there is no need to send any data, just the receiving part. I currently have 2 threads. the first for running the application and doing any GUI updates, the second for receiving any data from sockets and passing this through a delegate to my GUI thread.

For some reason it receives data a first time, and then stops getting new data, just outputting the same string it received the first time.

The following code is the MSDN example, slightly adjusted to fit my needs.

```
     // State object for receiving data from remote device.
    public class StateObject {
    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

public class AsynchronousClient {
    // The port number for the remote device.
    private const int port = 2003;
    static Socket currentsocket;
    static int packetsreceived = 0;

    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone = 
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone = 
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = 
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    // The response from the remote device.
    private static String response = String.Empty;


    public static void StartClient() {



        // Connect to a remote device.
        try {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
            // ip adress : xx.xx.xx.xxx
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Parse("xx.xx.xx.xxx"));
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            currentsocket = client;


            // Send test data to the remote device.
            //Send(client,"This is a test<EOF>");
            //sendDone.WaitOne();
            // Connect to the remote endpoint.
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).socketconnected = true;
                ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).loadingimage.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).statuslabel.Content = "Connected";
                ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).statuslabel.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
            }));

            // Receive the responses from the remote device.
            // main loop of receiving
            while (true)
            {

                if (!client.Connected)
                {
                    client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                    new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
                    connectDone.WaitOne();
                }

                if (client.Connected)
                {
                    Receive(client);
                    receiveDone.WaitOne();

                    packetsreceived++;
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).packetslabel.Content = packetsreceived;
                        ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).panel.Text += response;
                    }));

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    // Release the socket.
                    //client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    //client.Close();

                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).socketconnected = false;
                ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).connectbutton.Content = "Connect";
                ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).loadingimage.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).statuslabel.Content = "Disconnected";
                ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).statuslabel.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
            }));
        }
    }

private static void Receive(Socket client) {
        try {
            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult ar ) {
        try {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead));

                // Get the rest of the data.
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            } else {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                if (state.sb.Length > 1) {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

public static int Main(String[] args)
{
        StartClient();
}
```

Finally in my main thread:

```
// starts the socket thread and starts recieving
        private void connectbutton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!socketconnected)
            {
                statuslabel.Content = "Connecting..";
                loadingimage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                // socket stuff
                    socketThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                    {
                        AsynchronousClient.Main(new string[0]);
                        // Start the Dispatcher Processing
                        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
                    }));
                    // Set the apartment state
                    socketThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                    // Make the thread a background thread
                    socketThread.IsBackground = true;

                // Start the thread
                socketThread.Start();
                connectbutton.Content = "Disconnect";
            }
            else
            {
                socketThread.Abort();
                socketconnected = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What did you find when using the debugger to step through the code?

Comment: state.sb in ReceiveCallback is empty, no errors though

Comment: Continue debugging. Find out how the wrong value got output. Follow its path backwards to find the root cause.

Comment: I might have to add; i know for a fact that the server still is sending data out, since when i restart the application and connect again, i recieve new data. (sending integers that get incremented each time)

Comment: I was going to look at this, then I noticed the COM stuff:(

Comment: @GeorgeB does your UI get updated, are you getting into the `while` loop?  Are you getting stuck on `WaitOne`?

Comment: the UI does get updated, yes. I'm also in the while loop. The point is; whenever the Receive method gets called, and gets to the point where it checks wether state.sb.length > 1, it skips. That just means the received bytes are empty. Again I don't have a clue why it doesn't just continually receives data.

Comment: Your code is far from fine. Read up on how stream based protocols like TCP work. Or use a library like mine that takes care of everything for you: http://blog.gauffin.org/2014/06/easy-and-perfomant-clientserver-communication-with-protobuf-net-griffin-framework/

Comment: @jgauffin That does look interesting, I might give that a try at a later stage. In the end it does what i want it to do, which is receiving the latest data. When I have more time available I will surely give yours a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution.
The code was working fine, there was however, a problem with the connection.

A Thread.Sleep() was needed to ensure it connected properly to the socket. I found this by debugging this part of the code, and finding out that when I skipped through the code, it did not get new data, but when I stepped through it all, it DID receive new data.

I solved it as follows :

```
// Connect to a remote device.
    try {
        // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
        // ip adress : xx.xx.xx.xxx
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Parse("xx.xx.xx.xxx"));
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        currentsocket = client;


        // Send test data to the remote device.
        //Send(client,"This is a test<EOF>");
        //sendDone.WaitOne();
        // Connect to the remote endpoint.
        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
            new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
        connectDone.WaitOne();
        Thread.sleep(250);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).socketconnected = true;
            ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).loadingimage.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).statuslabel.Content = "Connected";
            ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).statuslabel.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
        }));
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else running into this problem.